# Linux: Find all occurrences of "string1" in files under a directory and replace them with "string2"

Tags: linux, find-and-replace

In linux, what's a good way to find all occurrences of "string1" in files under a directory and replace them with "string2"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fairly basic. Use sed with file globbing. Unless you mean every file in directory **and subdirectories**?

```
sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' /path_to_dir/*
```

**Edit:** In the case of literally **everything** under the directory

```
find /path_to_dir/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' '{}' +
```